Variation of the dual group and discrete L-parameter
Let $F$ be a $p$-adic field, $L_F=W_F\times \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ be the Weil-Deligne group of $F$.
Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over $F$, with split component of the center $A=A_G$. Let $\widehat{G}$ be the dual (complex reductive) group of $G$ and ${^LG}=\widehat{G}\rtimes \Gamma$ ($\Gamma=\Gamma_F$ the absolute Galois group) be the L-group.
In the study of Plancherel measure of discrete series, one needs a variation. Let $\widehat{G}^\natural$ be the dual group of $G/A$ (p.s. this is not the adjoint group in general). Since the center of $G/A$ is anisotropic, $Z(\widehat{G}^\natural)^\Gamma$ is a finite group. I already know that $\widehat{G}^\natural$ is indeed a subgroup of $\widehat{G}$.
My question is the following. Suppose $\phi:L_F\rightarrow {^LG}$ is a discrete L-parameter, so that $\mathcal{S}_\phi:=Z_{\widehat{G}}(\phi)/Z(\widehat{G})^\Gamma$ is a finite group. We consider $S_\phi^\natural:=Z_{\widehat{G}^\natural}(\phi)$ ($\widehat{G}^\natural$ is a subgroup of $\widehat{G}$). Here  $Z_{\widehat{G}^\natural}(\phi)$ is already a finite group, and we do not quotient it by $Z(\widehat{G}^\natural)^\Gamma$. Through examples I think we should have $$|S_\phi^\natural|/|S_\phi|=[X^*(A_G):X^*(G)],$$
But I do not know how to prove it in general. Here $X^*(A_G)$ (resp. $X^*(G)$) is the finitely generated abelian group of $F$-characters of $A_G$ (resp. $G$), and we identify $X^*(G)$ as a subgroup of $X^*(A_G)$ via the restriction morphism: $X^*(G)\ni \chi\mapsto \chi|_{A_G}\in  X^*(A_G)$.
This is quite clear from some basic examples, such as $G=\mathrm{GL}_n$, $G/A=\mathrm{PGL}_n$, the dual side are $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$. The point here is that the center of $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ contains $n$-th roots of unity and is of order $n=[X^*(A_G):X^*(G)]$ ($X^*(G)$ is generated by $\det$, restricted to the center of $\mathrm{GL}_n$ this is $n$-th power of the generator).
It seems that the number $[X^*(A_G):X^*(G)]$ encodes the relation between the order $|Z(\widehat{G}^\natural)^\Gamma|$ and $|\pi_0(Z(\widehat{G}))|$ (number of components). But I do not know how formulate the general formula. Can any expert give me some help/hint? Thanks a lot in advance!

i would ask this at mathoverflow
